# Dynamic google map InfoWindow loading content of last record in loop

Tags: google-maps

I'm having an issue where the content in my popup (when marker clicked) is showing the content of my last record.

I found a bit of help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576488/google-maps-infowindow-only-loading-last-record-on-markers), but I'm still having issues.

here's my code

collection.js

```
[
{
    "lat": "-25.363882",
    "lng": "131.044922",
    "category": "cat1",
    "title": "Heading #1",
    "description": "desc1",
    "imageurl": "http://ursispaltenstein.ch/blog/images/uploads_img/national_geographic_wallpaper_1.jpg",
    "pageLink": "http://www.google.com"
},
{
    "lat": "-26.363882",
    "lng": "200.044922",
    "category": "cat2",
    "title": "Heading #2",
    "description": "desc2",
    "imageurl": "http://www.creativepics.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/National-Geographic-Wallpapers-002.jpg",
    "pageLink": "http://www.google.com"
}
,
{
    "lat": "-28.363882",
    "lng": "81.044922",
    "category": "cat3",
    "title": "Heading #3",
    "description": "desc3",
    "imageurl": "http://blog.rapidsea.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/20080316-bora-bora-national-geographic.jpg",
    "pageLink": "http://www.google.com"
}
]
```

page javascript

```
var pointMap = { map: null }

$(function () {
    pointMap.init('#map_canvas', new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0), 2);
    pointMap.placeMarkers('collection.js');
});

pointMap.init = function (selector, latLng, zoom) {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: latLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map($(selector)[0], myOptions);
}

pointMap.placeMarkers = function (filename) {
    $.getJSON(filename, function (data) {
         for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
             var location = data[x];

             var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), parseFloat(location.lng));
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: point,
                 map: pointMap.map,
                 title: location.title
             });

             var popupContent = '<div id="locationContent">' +
                                      '<div>' + location.category + '</div>' +
                                      '<div>' + location.title + '</div>' +
                                      '<div>' + location.description + '</div>' +
                                      '<div><a href="' + location.pageLink + '">See This Story >></a></div>' +
                                      '<div><img width="250" src="' + location.imageurl + '" /></div>' +
                                 '</div>';

             var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        infoWindow.setContent(popupContent);
                        infoWindow.open(pointMap.map, this);
                    });
                }

       });
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   // javascript from above
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The markers all load in the correct places and windows all open in the correct places, but the content loaded in the InfoWindow (popupContent) is of my last record for all the markers.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 11):

So i've instead pushed the creation of the infoWIndow to a separate function instead of in the loop, and it seems to work.

updated code

```
pointMap.placeMarkers = function (filename) {
        $.getJSON(filename, function (data) {
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                var location = data[x];

                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), parseFloat(location.lng));
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: point,
                    map: pointMap.map,
                    title: location.title
                });

                var popupContent = '<div id="locationContent">' +
                                        '<div>' + location.category + '</div>' +
                                        '<div>' + location.title + '</div>' +
                                        '<div>' + location.description + '</div>' +
                                        '<div><a href="' + location.pageLink + '">See This Story >></a></div>' +
                                        '<div><img width="250" src="' + location.imageurl + '" /></div>' +
                                    '</div>';

                createInfoWindow(marker, popupContent);
            }

        });
    }

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    function createInfoWindow(marker, popupContent) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(popupContent);
            infoWindow.open(pointMap.map, this);
        });
    }
```