# Duplicate click event listeners for different markers : google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Introduction**

I am working with google maps, displaying markers having different infoWindow. I am making an ajax call to update the map markers with related info windows. After successful ajax call, map render function called and map updated 'rightly'.

**Problem**
After ajax call, map updated but the problem is that each marker has the same duplicate infowindow. In other words, infowindow is not binding with markers respectively.

**Javascript Code**

> I am sure problem is on clickEventListener. Comments are for info.

```
//map rendering start
                function renderMap(dd) {
                    console.log('after ', dd);
                    for (var a = 0; a < dd; a++) {
                        console.log('after ', dd);
                    }
                    var dataArr = [];
                    var mapProp = {
                        center: abc,
                        zoom: 12,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

                    for (var a = 0; a < dd.length; a++) {
                        dataArr.push({ location: new google.maps.LatLng(dd.location.coordinates[1], dd.location.coordinates[0]), weight: 2 });
                        var contentString = dd;
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: contentString
                        });

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: { lat: dd.location.coordinates[1], lng: dd.location.coordinates[0] },
                            label: "B",
                            map: map
                        });
                        console.log("before event listener", contentString);//Correctly displayed
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                            //when click on marker, console is logged
                            console.log("after event listener", contentString);//Wrongly log same contentString
                            infowindow.open(map.get('map'), marker);
                        });

                            // Add circle overlay and bind to marker
                          var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                                map: map,
                                radius: 5000,    // 10 miles in metres
                                fillColor: '#4682b4'
                            });

                        circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
                        //console.log(e.location] + ',' + e.location.coordinates[0]);

                        //start of inner for
                    }
                    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                        data: dataArr
                    });
                }
                //map rendering end
                function ajaxHeatMapHandler() {
                    var dataEl = $('#heatmapFilterArea');

                    var data = {};

                    //make ajax resquest
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/",
                        data: data,
                        success: function (response, status) {
                            heatmapTitle.text(responselength + ' entries');
                            renderMap(response);
                        },
                    });

                }
```

I am trying to figure out what has gone wrong and now turned to SO, if anyone have idea or knowledge for this problem, please do help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you sure you want to regenerate the map every time after AJAX called?

Comment: @LinShihHao thanks for reply, yes and i am considering other options also

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11010284/6139832), I think the problem is not the event handler, is the way how you create info window. Hope this help. ;)

Comment: Downvoters are encouraged to state the reason.So i can improve this question.

Comment: @LinShihHao thanks for the tip, that did solved the problem, i already stumbled on that question but didn't paid enough attention. You can post as answer, or mark it duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the great answer by Leigh [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11010284/6139832)

The problem is the way how you create info window, not the event handler I think.

Comment: H.M. instead of Leigh